# Count the number of sets in $S$ so $S\subseteq P(A)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

In one of previous exams there was the following question:

> Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ and $S\subseteq P(A)$.
> Given that each set in $S$ has $4$ members, and each member of $A$ belongs to $3$ sets of $S$. How many sets are there in $S$?

There are $8$ elements in $A$. Each one of them should be a member of a set of three sets. What does it mean? Does it mean that for each $a\in A$ there exist $B\subseteq S$ so $a\in B$? What $3$ means? Also, how do I count the number of sets in $S$?

Answer (score 1):

$P(A)$ is the set of all subsets of $A$ and hence $S$ is a set of some subsets of $A$, say $S=\{S_1,S_1,...,S_n\}$ where $|S_i|=4$.

The question says that each $a\in A$ is contained in exactly three sets in $S$, say $S_l,S_m,S_n$. If you were to write down the elements of all $S_i$, you would have written each element of $A$ thrice, i.e. $8\times3=24$ characters. The total number of characters written is also $\sum_i|S_i|=4n$. Thus $4n=24\iff n=6$.